# Word order in salutations

Tags: word-order, greetings, salutations

Can we use a reverse order in salutations? For example,

> Tom, hello/hi

instead of

> Hello/hi, Tom

Comment: Hi, @Diko. Welcome to ELU. Of course you can! But in the written form you'd probably transcribe it as *"Tom! Hi! Fancy meeting you here!"*. Just think of *"Tom!"* as an initial attention-grabbing device.

Comment: @FumbleFingers why not just post that as an answer?

Comment: @leigero: Because I don't really think questions at this level should be asked on ELU in the first place. And I *really* can't be bothered to discuss the grammatical difference between *"Tom! Come here!"* and *"Come here, Tom!"* here. I think the question should have been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) anyway, but to be honest I'd have though *every* language would allow you to simply call out the name of someone to attract their attention, before actually *saying* anything meaningful.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I've just seen two questions with this exact pattern of comments from you. I still don't understand what your objective is. If you don't think a question should be answered, why are you answering it? If you think a question doesn't belong on ELU, why aren't you downvoting it? If you think the question should be on ELL, are you flagging the question appropriately so the moderators can migrate it?

Comment: @MrHen: In this particular case I don't have a very strong opinion that the question would be better on ELL. The truth is I think it's a trivial question *anywhere*, for the reason I gave in both comments (I assume every language has some equivalent to *Hello/Hi/Hey*, and therefore *all* speakers can reasonably say both *"Tom! Hi!"* and *"Hi! Tom!"*). In fact, I *didn't* closevote this particular question though, because it's always possible someone might say there's a language that doesn't work like that. Which I *would* find interesting, even though I don't see how that would be On Topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You answered one of my three questions. The reason I ask, by the way, is because I still don't understand why you find it appropriate to answer a trivial question in the comments but if you find it inappropriate to answer a trivial question in an answer.

Comment: @MrHen: As regards answering Off Topic questions in comments, I set out my stall in [this ELL meta answer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/945/126). And yes - I *do* flag a certain number of questions asking if the mods will migrate them from ELU to ELL. But there's still no real consensus on where to draw the line (witness this interaction! :), so I'm taking a *softly softly, catchee monkey* approach on that front (and waiting to see exactly what *kind* of questions tend to get migrated).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But your meta post doesn't address why you think answering a trivial question in comments is appropriate but answering a trivial question in an answer is inappropriate. And, in this case, you didn't vote to close... so why did you not answer in an answer?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Btw, the only reason I care is because ELU has a hard time close "borderline" Off-Topic or Trivial questions and they just languish here unclosed and unanswered. Can I get you to compromise and move the answer-in-comment to an answer-in-answer if the question is not voted closed within 1 month?

Comment: @MrHen: You'll have to bear in mind I'm only human, so I may sometimes be inconsistent. But in this particular case I do specifically recall thinking at the time that it would be interesting to know if there are any languages that don't have an equivalent to *Hello/Hi/Hey*. So I imagine I didn't closevote because I thought leaving it open here might increase the chances of finding out about that. Incidentally, I've just noticed that if I look at [most downvoted ELU questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?page=719&sort=votes), many of them look like good candidates for ELL.

Comment: ...your "compromise" sounds good to me though. If a Q hasn't been closed or migrated after a few weeks, it may as well be "finished" using the next best available method.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Understandable. I was just curious about your reasons. I think ELU could do a better job migrating things to ELL... but I'm not actually sure how many questions do get migrated. The distinction between the two sites is still a little unclear to me. I appreciate the compromise, though. I don't really *disagree* with your behavior so much as I just have conflicting goals. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14068/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-mrhen)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reverse the order of salutations, both at initial greeting ("Kitty, hello!") and at farewell. One famous instance of the latter is in the classic (1959) country western song "El Paso," by Marty Robbins, in which a cowboy shoots another cowboy over the love of "wicked Feleena," escapes, but then is mortally wounded by a band of vengeful cowboys as he tries to return to town to see Feleena again. The final line of the song:

> One final kiss and Feleena, goodbye.